# Reload picture after clickin on other page on site

Tags: html, asp.net, gif

I have gif picture on every page on my site, and only when i first time open page my gif started to "move", but on others page it doesn't, its just html code

`<div class="rhs-pc">
            <img src="images/PC-slow.gif" alt="pc animation" />
        </div>`

What should i do to reload gif on every page?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your gif is accessible by relative path from each page of your site. For example site structure:

```
/index.html
/music/list.html
/music/favorite.html
/images/PC-slow.gif
```

Gif will be accessible from `index.html`, but it will be broken on `/music/list.html` because browser will try to load `/music/images/PC-slow.gif`.
Use [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag to prevent that, or use full path: `/images/PC-slow.gif` instead of `images/PC-slow.gif`.

Comment: No it is still same, it doesnt want to move gif even when i hit f5 only refreshes with ctr+f5. One more thing, when i put site localy its reload gid on every page but when i put it on hosting then gif doesnt "move"..

Comment: I suppose its because of chache.

Comment: What do you mean "move gif"? Gif isn't animated? Could you give a link to your site?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: you better give us a link to your site, maybe it's just something wrong with you browser